# How to resolve Email validation error in Reactive Forms: Object is possibly 'null' in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this code in Angular-11:

This is the signup typescript component for the code.

```js
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {

  form!: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
  ) {}

  // tslint:disable-next-line:typedef
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
      confirm_password: ['', Validators.required]
    })
  }

  // tslint:disable-next-line:typedef
  get f() {
    return this.form.controls;
  }

  // tslint:disable-next-line:typedef
  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    const formData = this.form.getRawValue();

    const data = {
      name: formData.name,
      email: formData.email,
      password: formData.password,
      confirm_password: formData.confirm_password
    };

    // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.form.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    const header = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };
    return this.api.post('auth/signup', data, header).subscribe(
      (result: any) => {
        this.router.navigate(['/auth']);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Then the signup.html:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="example@email.com" formControlName="email" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.email.errors }">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.required">Email is required</div>
    <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.email">Email must be a valid email address: example@email.com</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I tried to serve the project, I got this error:

```
Error: src/app/signup/signup.component.html:59:48 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

59                     <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.required">Email is required</div>
                                              ~~~~~~~~

 src/app/signup/signup.component.ts:13:16
13   templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component SignupComponent.


Error: src/app//signup/signup.component.html:60:48 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

60                     <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.email">Email must be a valid email address: example@email.com</div>
```

All the other validations worked except for the email. I have on it for some time now. I tried to figure it out but no solution still.

What do I do to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `hasError` method of control instead of `error.errorName`; it is returning boolean; `true` when the error exists

`control.hasError('errorName')`

**Usage Example**

```
f.email.hasError('required')
```

or

**the second way is just add a question mark before the key name**

like this

```
f.email.errors?.required
```

**this is the equivalent of**

```
if(f.email.errors !== null || f.email.errors !== undefined) {
   f.email.errors.required
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `?` to `errors`.

```
<div *ngIf="f.email.errors?.required">Email is required</div>
<div *ngIf="f.email.errors?.email">Email must be a valid email address: example@email.com</div>
```